# Forwarding a ref to all pages (route components) just to apply it to the <main> and have a Skip Navigation Link (button). Is there no better way?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, accessibility, use-ref, react-forwardref

I have been on it for a while now, researching useRef, forwardRef just to be able to add the Skip Navigation Link to my React project. Since multiple sources say that ElementById and querySelector are not the correct way to do it, I ended up forwarding a ref to ALL my routes. Then on each page I forward the ref further to a RefMain component. It all seems like a massive complication for a small accessibility feature.

```
const App = () => {
  const beginningOfMainRef = useRef(null);

  const handleFocusMain = () => beginningOfMainRef.current.focus();

  return (
    <Theme>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <SkipNavigationButton onClick={handleFocusMain}>
        Skip Navigation Links
      </SkipNavigationButton>
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage ref={beginningOfMainRef} />} />
        <Route
          path="/distributors"
          element={<DistributorsPage ref={beginningOfMainRef} />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/contacts"
          element={<ContactsPage ref={beginningOfMainRef} />}
        />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </Theme>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Than in each page:

```
const AboutPage = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <RefMain ref={ref}>
      <h1>hi, i'm about</h1>
    </RefMain>
  );
});
export default AboutPage;
```

And finally:

```
const RefMain = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <Main>
      <BeginningOfMain tabIndex="-1" ref={ref}>
        {props.title} main content
      </BeginningOfMain>
      {props.children}
    </Main>
  );
});

export default RefMain;
```

This is of course a simplified example with a reduced number of Pages. Looking at the routes with passed ref, they are anything, but dry. Am I missing some neat trick here? I tried using useRef within the RefMain component, but that left me unable to pass the ref to the handler function higher in the tree (App.js).

Comment: After some testing the scales are tipped even further. The Skip navigation link is only available as the first tab index at the initial Home page load. Being a SPA app, react doesn't reset focus location, virtually eliminating the accessibility gains after loading a new Route (focus is near the NavLink I clicked, and away from the skip navigation link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you apply `RefMain` in each routed component it would better to abstract it as a layout route component instead of a wrapper component around each page's content. Instead of rendering the `children` prop it renders an [`Outlet`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet) component for nested routes to render their content into.

```
const RefMain = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [title, setTitle] = React.useState();

  return (
    <Main>
      <BeginningOfMain tabIndex="-1" ref={ref}>
        {title} main content
      </BeginningOfMain>
      <Outlet context={{ setTitle }} />
    </Main>
  );
});

export const RefWrapper = ({ children, title }) => {
  const { setTitle } = useOutletContext();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTitle(title);
  }, [title]);

  return children;
};

export default RefMain;
```

```
const AboutPage = () => {
  return (
    <h1>hi, i'm about</h1>
  );
}
export default AboutPage;
```

You can use another ref and `div` element to set the focus back to the top of the page when the page location updates.

```
const App = () => {
  const topRef = useRef();
  const beginningOfMainRef = useRef(null);

  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    topRef.current.scrollIntoView();
    topRef.current.focus();
  }, [location.pathname]);

  const handleFocusMain = () => beginningOfMainRef.current.focus();

  return (
    <Theme>
      <div ref={topRef} tabIndex={-1} />
      <GlobalStyle />
      <SkipNavigationButton onClick={handleFocusMain}>
        Skip Navigation Links
      </SkipNavigationButton>
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<RefMain ref={beginningOfMainRef} />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route
            path="/distributors"
            element={(
              <RefWrapper title="Distributors">
                <DistributorsPage />
              </RefWrapper>
            )}
          />
          <Route
            path="/contacts"
            element={(
              <RefWrapper title="Contacts">
                <ContactsPage />
              </RefWrapper>
            )}
          />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </Theme>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I didn't stand up any sandbox to test this but it is my belief it should be close to the desired behavior you describe. If there are issues let me know and I'll work on a live demo.

Comment: This is great! <Outlet> was exactly what I was looking for. Since I scrapped the title from the focus-able component (before your answer), it is now the simple, clean solution I was looking for. Didn't try your exact code, but I think <div ref={topRef} /> needs a tabindex="-1" to be focus-able. Is there a reason to include topRef.current.scrollIntoView(); ? It seems to work fine without it. Finally, I changed the dependency to [location.key] in order to get the focus reset with links matching the current location pathname. Could this cause problems?

Comment: @HowToNoob Ah, the `scrollIntoView` might *not* be necessary, but I've had times in the past where the entire page was scrollable and simply setting the focus on an element didn't bring it into view, so it was necessary then. No, `location.key` or `location.pathname` are very likely fine.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a react answer but a skip link should be very simple. They're typically the first DOM element on the page and all it does is link to a spot further down on the page. A skip link does not link to a different page.

```html
<a href="#skip">skip to main</a>
...
<main id="skip" tabindex="-1">
  stuff on the page
</main>
```

> It all seems like a massive complication for a small accessibility feature.

Are you applying your personal preference as to how useful that **small** accessibility feature is?  Do you use a sip-and-puff device? Do you get worn down by how many times you have to puff to navigate through all the items in a top level menu just to get to the main part of the page?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It presents the absolute simplest method of utilizing a Skip Navigation Link when writing html. My question is related to the complications that come with using JSX, React Router, specifically useRef, forwardRef instead of DOM element selectors, as well as avoiding any className (classes) and id attributes in favor of StyledComponents.
Yes, it absolutely is up to my preference, whether this feature is worth over complicating my code.
Yes this is a small, LONGER way to access a one-button feature (Next landmark) that is popular with sip-and-puff device users.

Comment: Yes, understood about the framework getting in the way of the simplicity.  That's unfortunate and sorry I can't comment on react. My other comment about whether this is a **small** feature is relative to the user. For someone that doesn't need a skip link, this is indeed a small feature. But to the user that really needs it, this is a huge feature. My point was we have to be careful on making a judgement call on how significant a feature is if we're only looking at it from our personal standpoint.